# how to clean and build a project using vbnet code

Tags: vb.net, build, msbuild, network-programming, solution

I have a list of vb.net projects and their solution files on the network, what I want is code to be able to take each path and build the .sln file? It’s not hard getting the files and creating the loop, but is there somekind of vb.net code that can build .sln files? I know you can do this is a batch file but want the equivalent in vb.net if possible. Hope someone can help

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Doing various amounts of googling however the searches seem to go round in circles and keep bringing me to articles on how to simply build or create a new project (not helpful), seems if no one knows may as well begin to write a batch file.